# Set icalendar date start and date end timezone

Tags: icalendar

I'm using MVC4 to create ics files and sent them by mail. But i don't know how to set my DTSTART and DTEND timezone.

I know the problem is with the Z at the end

```
    a.WriteLine("DTSTART:20150814T000000Z")
    a.WriteLine("DTEND:20150814T110000Z")
```

I need to set it to GMT -6, Central America time or more especific Managua Nicaragua timezone.

Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line like this should do it:

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/Managua:20150814T000000
```

You officially also need to include a VTIMEZONE object with all the relevant timezone transition information for your timezone, but almost every client can work without that data